# PHP not 'exec'ing Rscript when it works in cmd

Tags: php, r

So I'm attempting to use exec to exec an Rscript from php to no avail. The command inside the exec works perfectly in cmd even from the same location folder so I'm not sure why it wont in php. I'm getting no errors from php (aside from saying the resulting image that is supposed to be produced doesn't exist).Safemode on the ini is off. I'm using XAMPP Apache to host this I'm unsure if that'll affect anything. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css">
<style>
    h1 {color: white; margin-left: 26px; font-family: "Trebuchet MS"; font-weight: normal; height: 60px; font-size: 1.275rem}
</style>
</head>

<html>

<body style="text-align: center">
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: ----
 * Date: 20/03/17
 * Time: 7:13 PM
 */
echo "<form action='PhpToR.php' method='get'>";
echo "Number values to generate: <input type='text' name='N' />";
echo "<input type='submit' />";
echo "</form>";
if( isset($_GET['N']))
{
    $N = $_GET['N'];
    // execute R script from shell
    // this will save a plot at temp2.png to the filesystem

    exec("Rscript ~/../my_rscript.R $N");

    // return image tag

    echo("<img src='~/../images/temp2.png' /> ");
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `exec('command', $output)` try to print $output to check if there are an errors;

Comment: Array ( [0] => 'Rscript' is not recognized as an internal or external command, [1] => operable program or batch file. )

OK seems to be a XAMPP permissions error then.

Answer (score 0):

All came down to me forgetting to reset XAMPP after adding Rscript to the PATH.

Comment: Hello UserK2014, could you tell me how you fixed it? What do you mean "All came down to me forgetting to reset XAMPP after adding Rscript to the PATH."

Comment: Been a while so can't remember for sure, but I assume I just meant literally resetting/restarting the XAMPP server after adding the RScript package (which I presumably did while XAMPP  was still running).